My own NestJS project don't want to be dependent on the proto files in the same repository
I want to maintain proto files in a separate repository, this repo only has proto files. Then implement specific server logic in other repositories (do not source directly from the proto file). Something like this:
The NestJS official guideline shows:
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
  transport: Transport.GRPC,
  options: {
    package: 'hero',
    protoPath: join(__dirname, 'hero/hero.proto'),
  },
});

It must involve the protoPath in the codebase. But I don't want .proto file to be in this codebase.
What's compenents should be involed?
Is there any runnable demo for this?
